# When are curves irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This question might be too vague, but we know lots of things about irreducible curves, but when I'm given a curve I often can't tell if it's irreducible, so I don't know if those things apply to my curve. I wonder if there's any way of telling if a (projective) curve is irreducible, without trying to factor the polynomial.

I read somewhere that a cubic regular curve in the complex projective plane is irreducible. Is there a generalization of this, e.g. for non-cubic curves, in a projective space over some other field, or in a higher-dimensional projective space? And is there some other similar results?

Comment: Smooth curves are irreducible if and only if it is connected.

Comment: In addition to that, hypersurfaces are always connected, so smooth cubics (or quartics, etc) are definitely irreducible.

Answer (score 2):

I hope to help you.

If $V$ is a curve, then $V$ is a closed set in Zariski topology $\Bbb A^n_k$. The following are equivalent:

$(1)$ V is irreducible
$(2)$ any two non-empty open sets of $V$ have a non-empty intersection
$(3)$ Every non-empty open subset is dense in $V$
$(4)$ Every non-empty open subset is connected
$(5)$ Every non-empty open subset is irreducible